# Infinite scrolling in homepage

Tags: javascript, wordpress, infinite-scroll

With "Oxygen Builder", I created a very light page (section, repeater, div, title : that's all) with the code of "Infinite Scroll" in a Code Block : everything runs good.
The "Infinite Scroll" scrolls all posts of all pages.

I made this page as homepage :
the "Infinite Scroll" runs but with only posts of the first page.
The first page is repeated indefinitely.
I don't know if the problem comes from Wordpress or Oxygen Builder.
First of all, I tried with "Yith Infinite Scrolling" (with "Oxygen Builder") and I had the same problem.
Of ccourse, as soon as I set another homepage, the infinite scroll runs good again.
Do you know how to fix that ?

The JS code I use is:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/infinite-scroll@4/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
    (function($) {
        $('#_dynamic_list-3-227.oxy-dynamic-list').infiniteScroll({
            path: '.next',
            append: '.infinite-scroll',
            history: false,
            hideNav: '.oxy-repeater-pages',
        });
    })(jQuery);
},500)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution from Christina on the facebook group:

I had the same problem. The support gave me this answer, which is working:
There's a known issue with pagination on static home pages. To get it to work, I've added a Code Block above your Repeater with the following code on the PHP & HTML tab:

```
<?php
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    }
    else {
        $paged = 1;
    }
    query_posts('posts_per_page=2&paged=' . $paged);
?>
```

If you change the number of items per page in the future, you will also need to change it in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. It happened in versions before 3.9.
This issue has been resolved since 3.9 BETA 1.

In the meantime, you can add this in the plugin code snippet or functions.php in the child theme. I got this code from oxyextras support before: https://gist.github.com/wplit/8548f32ca9e703fe62284cd23d5c1245

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pagination_fix_static_homepage' );
function pagination_fix_static_homepage( $query ) {
    $front_page_id        = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
    $current_page_id      = $query->get( 'page_id' );
    $is_static_front_page = 'page' === get_option( 'show_on_front' );
    
    if ( $is_static_front_page && $front_page_id == $current_page_id  ) {
        if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
            $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
        } elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
            $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
        } else {
            $paged = 1;
        }
        $paged = intval( $paged );
        $query->set( 'paged', $paged );
    }
    return $query;
}
```